# Android - Use of Vertical "Number Slider" Widget

Tags: android, widget, slider

On my android phone (Sony Ericsson Xperia X8), in the built in alarm clock there's a screen where the user can select hour and minute via a nice translucent vertical number slider, as below:

[image]

For an android app (for android version 2.1 and up) I'm developing I'd like to use something similar for the user to pick a number (not an hour or minute, however) from a predefined range.

I'm not obsessed about using the exact same widget (for example, something similar but horizontally oriented would do just fine), but the main things I'm after are a) the use of sliding to move the numbers across and b) having the available numbers in a predefined range.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious if there is any horizontal slider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/.

Comment: Thanks, tabbykitten - looks promising. I will check it out as soon as I can download the source code

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom [`Spinnner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) and specify for it custom `background`, `dropDownViewResource` etc. You can have a look at this tutorial : [Android Custom Spinners](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57).